# Will Concepts replace SFINAE?

Tags: c++

Concepts likely to be in the C++ standard (C++17, or maybe C++20).

So I wonder if this new feature can completely replace SFINAE, or it's just a small version of SFINAE with nice error reports and type checking.

Are there any cases when SFINAE is the only choice instead of using Concepts?

Comment: Maybe in the sense `for` “replaced” `goto`?

Comment: That would be very nice.

Comment: I don't see expression SFINAE being phased out for basic things that don't require full fledged concepts.

Comment: @Rapptz Could you give a simple example?

Comment: What do you mean with "replace SFINAE"? Do you mean that substitution failure would be an error? That would break a lot of existing code. What's the reason for doing that?

Comment: No, I mean that in new code I don't need to use SFINAE anymore.

Comment: @DDrmmr the question is about the techniques that dispatch between template specializations/overloads using SFINAE, not SFINAE itself I reckon.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With [concepts](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) taking shape and being implemented in compilers (currently only gcc >= 6.1 with option `-fconcepts`), it appears that they can do everything that you could have done using [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) only much better (much clearer expression of intent and producing concise error messages), and much more (such as abbreviated templates).

So the simple answer is **YES**.